# Passing both TRUE and FALSE to a parameter in a SQL function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL function which looks basically like this...

```
create or replace function myfunction(myparam boolean)
returns table 
language 'sql'
as $BODY$
  select * from mytable where myIndicator = myparam
$BODY$
```

...and it works just fine. But, I have now been told that this function may be asked to return all cases where `myparam` is `true` or `false` *or both*. However, this code fails because `array` is not a possible parameter type:

```
create or replace function myfunction(couldBeTrueOrFalseOrBoth array)
returns table 
language 'sql'
as $BODY$
  select * from mytable where myIndicator in couldBeTrueOrFalseOrBoth
$BODY$
```

Is there an easy solution here?

Comment: would a `IS NOT NULL` not cover all cases

Comment: Yes, but it can also be IS TRUE or IS FALSE. To my understanding I can't use a CASE statement in a WHERE clause.

Comment: `boolean[]` as in `select '{"t", "f"}'::boolean[]; {t,f}`?

Comment: Boolean[] is not supported, though maybe I could try char[].

Comment: What makes you think it is not?  The query I provided shows that `boolean[]` is supported.  Also from here [Arrays](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html): "Arrays of any built-in or user-defined base type, enum type, composite type, range type, or domain can be created." Provide Postgres version and any error messages you got when using `boolean[]` as update to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `null` for this:

```
create or replace function myfunction(myparam boolean)
returns table (...)
language sql
as $BODY$
  select * 
  from mytable 
  where myIndicator = myparam
     or myparam is null  
$BODY$
```

To get all rows use:

```
select *
from myfunction(null)
```

You can also use an optional parameter:

```
create or replace function myfunction(myparam boolean default null)
returns table (...)
language sql
as $BODY$
  select * 
  from mytable 
  where myIndicator = myparam
     or myparam is null  
$BODY$
```

Then calling it without a parameter is also possible (and the same as passing null)

```
select *
from myfunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**

Use a string as the parameter with the options "true", "false" and "both". Then in your function use case statement to determine wether it is "true", "false" or "both".

```
create or replace function myfunction(myparam string)
returns table 
language 'sql'
as $BODY$
  CASE
      WHEN myParam='true'
      THEN select * from mytable where myIndicator = true
      WHEN myParam='false'
      THEN select * from mytable where myIndicator = false
      WHEN myParam='both'
      THEN select * from mytable
  END
$BODY$
```

**Option 2:**

Just call your function twice, with all the cases it needs the answer to.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but the actual function code has been shortened for this example. Doing it this way would lead to more than 500 lines of code, difficult to edit or troubleshoot.

Comment: you can use an IF..ELSE statement as well, IF "both"->return all ELSE->return where param. @a_horse_with_no_name def might work better tho